# Access Restructuring SQL/Design View Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hoping someone can help me with the following.

I am new to Access and have been developing a simple database to handle the ticketing of trucks in and out of my work. At the moment I am trying to write a query that will search the tickets based on 6 different criteria which can be input from a separate form. I want the query to match when the ticket and form match but also to match when the search criteria is left blank. Five of the fields have essentially the same structure which is:

```
[Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![cbTicketSummaryCustomer] 
OR [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![cbTicketSummaryCustomer] Is Null
```

and one which is a date field which I structured:

```
Between [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryStartDate] 
And [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryEndDate] Or >
[Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryStartDate] 
And [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryEndDate] Is Null 
Or [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryStartDate] Is Null 
And <[Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryEndDate] 
Or [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryStartDate] Is Null 
And [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryEndDate] Is Null
```

This all seemed to work fine but after a while of running it I looked at the code again and saw that Access had modified it as per the picture.
[Screenshot of Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me1x0.png)
This still works for a while but Access seems to keep adding more code which eventually causes a "Query Too Complex" error.

Appreciate if someone could explain why Access is doing this and what I am doing wrong to cause this.

Regards,

Ryan

Comment: Did you build this query in design view or type into SQL view? Parentheses are critical when mixing AND and OR operators. Your query has none. I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: I built the query in design view so I assume Access would have added the parentheses correctly and as I said it worked correctly initially before Access adds more code causing the "Query too complex" error.

Comment: Well, since I don't use dynamic parameterized queries I don't have experience with this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I assume it is condensing the the two conditions I have as the criteria for each field into one and building more rows for each possible case but not sure why Access would do that.

Comment: I don't think you need this complex combined criterium. Just do them as all the other criteria, e.g. `>[Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryStartDate] OR [Forms]![frmTicketSummary]![TicketSummaryStartDate] Is Null`, and apply them both to the same table column.

Comment: I also use vba and build filter criteria for a number of reasons.  The problem with the code decaying is probably from a combination of factors.  complicated access queries are brittle.  references to form parameters in access are brittle.  access stores queries built in the designer in some form of code.  complicated queries  don't always come back the same way when they are encoded and decoded.  However every time this has happened to me the query didn't work anyway.  see my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

In short your query is so complicated I'm surprised it is working.  I'm assuming you want to build a form to search your tblTicket where if form boxes are left empty they don't restrict the search.  to fix the query remove all the calculated variables based on form parameters:
Here is my demo tblTicket:

[image]

Here is the improved query:

[image]

no need to use the [row labeled or] a row is included if for every one of our criteria it either matches the value on the form or is null.  (note I use human readable public properties instead of those long access based references to the search form controls).  next hook up the query to a form as a search form and provide some combo boxes to filter the results:

[image]

then you have to manually hook up the sub-form to the combo boxes:

```
'filter the subform manually after changing combo boxes:
Private Sub cmbCarrier_AfterUpdate()
Carrier = cmbCarrier.Value
Me.qryTickets_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmbCustomer_AfterUpdate()
Customer = cmbCustomer.Value
Me.qryTickets_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmbIsInvoiced_AfterUpdate()
IsInvoiced = cmbIsInvoiced.Value
Me.qryTickets_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmbLoadDate_AfterUpdate()
LoadDate = cmbLoadDate.Value
Me.qryTickets_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmbProduct_AfterUpdate()
Product = cmbProduct.Value
Me.qryTickets_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmbTransportPaid_AfterUpdate()
TransportPaid = cmbTransportPaid.Value
Me.qryTickets_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
'the designer can find public functions in code modules so the public definitions are put in module 1
Option Compare Database

Public Customer As Long
Public Product As Long
Public Carrier As Long
Public LoadDate As Date
Public IsInvoiced As Boolean
Public TransportPaid As Boolean
Public Docket As Long

Public Function GetCustomer() As Long
GetCustomer = Customer
End Function
Public Function GetProduct() As Long
GetProduct = Product
End Function
Public Function GetCarrier() As Long
GetCarrier = Carrier
End Function
Public Function GetLoadDate() As Date
GetLoadDate = LoadDate
End Function
Public Function GetIsInvoiced() As Boolean
GetIsInvoiced = IsInvoiced
End Function
Public Function GetTransportPaid() As Boolean
GetTransportPaid = TransportPaid
End Function
Public Function GetDocket() As Long
GetDocket = Docket
End Function
```

*docketID uses the same type of criteria expression as the other variables

Comment: Hi Mazoula, Just wanted to than you for your response. I have had some time off work so haven't had a chance to look this over in detail but will hopefully get a chance to get back to it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the best way to approach this problem is two fold:

First, ignore solutions that hard code expressions in the query.

Second, ignore solutions that force you to write a truckload of code.

But, you can trade a "wee bit" of code for VASTLY reducing the sql, and the code.

So, in the query that drives that form, remove ALL of the forms! expressions and criteria.

It should be just clean SQL - and with NO external dependences, and NO forms! expressions.

What you do is pass a "where" clause to the form, and this feature is designed to solve and attack this problem for you.

The code thus on that filter form can look like this:

```
Dim strWhere   As String      ' our filter


If IsNull(CarridID) = False Then
   ' add carrier
   strWhere = "(CarrierFK = " & Me.cboCarrier & ")"
End If

If IsNull(chkInvoiced) = False Then
   If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
   strWhere = strWhere & "(IsInvoiced = " & Me.chkInvoiceed & ")"
End If

If IsNull(cboCustomerID) = False Then
   If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strwhare & " AND "
   strWhere = strWhere & "(CustoerFK = " & Me.cboCustomer & ")"
End If

If IsNull(Me.TicketSummaryStartDate) = False Then
   If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "

   strWhere = strWhere & "LoadDate >= " & Me.TicketSummaryStartDate
   If IsNull(Me.TicketSummaryEndDate) = False Then
      ' add ending date
      strWhere = strWhere & " AND LoadDate <= " & Me.TicketSumaryEndDate
   End If
   strWhere = strWhere & ")"
End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmEditTrucks", , , strWhere
```

So note how:
You do NOT have hard coded and huge ugly forms!formname!column name in you sql. This means you can RE-USE the sql query in code, in forms, and in reports. (and NOT have some specific form that may, or may not be open).

You certainly do have to write some code, but that code is FAR less work, hassle and is far easier to maintain the that huge ugly query.

So, you need one if/then block as per above for each control that is "optional". If the controls on the filter form are blank, then they are ignored and not part of the query.

The huge bonus is then the same prompt filter form can also launch reports etc, and once again that simple query remains clean, and thus the form/report etc. based on such queries are NOT bound and tied to one particular form.

It also means that you can re-use the query, but even better is you can add over time additional criteria to the prompt form, BUT NOT HAVE to modify the actual query! (as long as the columns exist for your criteria, then you don't have to play with, and mess with the query builder.

And the above suggesting and advantages means that the sql remains nice and clean.

So, start to adopt the "where" clause of the open report, or open form. You not only be glad you did, and achieve  optional criteria, but you achieve this with out having to mess up a perfectly nice and clean sql query.

The only down side, is you have to follow in code:
For PK/FK values etc., you can just use the given number
For string/text values, you have to surround with quotes (single are fine).
For date critera, you have to force USA format, and also surround with #.

So, for above, I would suggest one helper function to help you with the dates.

eg this:

```
  Public Function quDateT(dt As Date) As String
     ' return formatted date
     quDateT = "#" & Format(dt, "mm\/dd\/yyyy HH:NN:SS") & "#"
  End Function
```

So, the date code block example becomes:

```
If IsNull(Me.TicketSummaryStartDate) = False Then
   If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & " AND "

   strWhere = strWhere & "LoadDate >= " & qudateT(Me.TicketSummaryStartDate)
   If IsNull(Me.TicketSummaryEndDate) = False Then
      ' add ending date
      strWhere = strWhere & " AND LoadDate <= " & qudateT(Me.TicketSumaryEndDate)
   End If
   strWhere = strWhere & ")"
End If
```

If you don't set (choose) a combo box, check box etc. on that filter form, then the value of that combo box or text box, or date will be null, and we don't add it to the final criteria.

As you are finding out, putting forms! expression in queries can get really messy real fast.

Even worse, is now that the query is now "married" and attached to that ONE form. Often, I have a nice query that I could use MANY times for different reports, and often even that same query could be used for reports...but then someone comes along and puts in a expression that means the query is ONLY good when that form is opened.

Worse, is very hard to control things like having 5 combo boxes, but the user only selects restrictions in 3 of the combo boxes...and wants the other 2 to be ignore.

I could probably write another 10 or pages as to why putting forms expressions in queries is bad (besides...it makes the queries real ugly, and hard to read. and, the sql then is not standard anymore (it will not work with server based systems either).

So, the solution use now is simply to take the values from the form, and build your own where clause in code. That way, you simply design the reports (or forms), and attached them to the query, BUT NO FORMS! conditions are placed in the query.

To "send" the conditions to the report (or form), you simply use the "where" clause. This is exactly why ms-access has this feature…and it solves a zillion problems…and will reduce your development costs by a substantial amount.

Take a look at the following screen shots to see what I mean:

http://www.kallal.ca/ridesrpt/ridesrpt.html

The code to make those above screens work and launch the report with the selected restrictions when you hit the "print" button is easy:

```
dim   strWhere       as string

 'select sales rep combo

if isnull(cboSalesRep) = false then

   strWhere = "SalesRep = " & cboSalesRep & ""

end if

select what City for the report

if isnull(cboCity) = false then
   if strWhere <> "" then
      strWhere = strWhere " and "
   endif
strWhere = strWhere & "CityID = " & cobCity & ""
end if
```

Note how the 2nd combo test is setup. You can add as "many" more conditions you want. Lets say we have a check box to only include Special Customers. We can add to our very nice prompt screen a check box to

[x] Show Only Special customers

The code we add would be:

```
if chkSpeicalOnly = True then
   if strWhere <> "" then
      strWhere = strWhere " and "
   endif
   strWhere = strWhere & "(SpecialCust  =  true )"
end if
```

For sure, each combo and control we add to the nice report screen takes a bit of code, but no more messy then the query builder. and this way, each query is nice and clean, and free of a bunch of HIGHLY un-maintainable forms! expressions.

Further, it means you can re-use the same query for different reports, and have no worries about some form that is supposed to be open. So, a tiny bit more code eliminates the messy query problem.. For me, this is very worth while trade.

Once you adopt the above, you never go back to messy forms! expressions.

The other huge advantage? Well, not only can the query be re-used, but it can be used with sql server and other systems. In other words, the instant you introduce those message expressions into the query builder is the VERY SAME instant you quite much damaged the query and it is of no use elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Thanks Albert, I haven't had a chance to review your answer fully yet but will hopefully have some time soon. Appreciate the detailed response.